# How to change the plotting direction in a heatmap?

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, heatmap

I've made this heatmap.

[image: Heatmap]

The issue is that the data was plotted from left to right. How can I :

1. reverse the y axis? starting 0 from the bottom, 176000 to the top?
2. change the plotting method and group the values per SSR. The plotting should start from the bottom up to the top, filling the first column then moving on to the next.
3. center the tick marks

This is the code that I've used for the heatmap

```
bin_size = 11000

heatmap_data = np.zeros((len(ssr2_locations), seq_length // bin_size))
ssr_labels = list(ssr2_locations.keys())
for i, ssr in enumerate(ssr2_locations):
    ssr_locations = np.array(ssr2_locations[ssr]) # convert to NumPy array
    for j in range(seq_length // bin_size):
        heatmap_data[i, j] = np.sum((ssr_locations >= j*bin_size) & (ssr_locations < (j+1)*bin_size))

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.imshow(heatmap_data, cmap='Blues')
plt.colorbar()

# Set x-axis labels
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, heatmap_data.shape[0]), ssr_labels)

# Set y-axis labels
ytick_labels = np.arange(0, seq_length, bin_size)
ytick_positions = ytick_labels // bin_size
plt.yticks(ytick_positions, ytick_labels)

plt.title("SSR Density Heatmap")
plt.xlabel("SSR")
plt.ylabel("Nucleotide Sequence Position")
plt.show()
```

I try to manipulate it but multiple issues are arising whenever I modify the code.

Comment: You should carefully read the `imshow` docs, I think that will help you figure out the first two questions. Then, did you fully digest [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) or consider using [`seaborn.heatmap()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)?

Comment: One of your issues: `imshow(..., origin='lower')` would start plotting from the bottom. (As most image formats store their information upper to lower, by default `imshow` starts at the top.) To exchange x and y you can transpose the matrix: `imshow(heatmap_data.T, ...)`. Note that `imshow` also has a parameter `extent=` to set the x and y ranges.